# google map plugin zindex conflict with popup and other elements

Tags: cordova, google-maps, jquery-mobile, z-index

I use [googlemap plugin](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/wiki/Tutorial-for-Windows) for phonegap. In my program I have one pop up window in my phonegap application.
however I set z-index for my pop up and google map has no z-index , but buttons in pop up windows not work *(when I click on pop up, my map moved and no popup)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map is native and will notice every touch. If you have a popup you have to disable this behavior before the popup is showing:

```
 map.setClickable(false);
```

And after the popup is closed you set it back:

```
map.setClickable(true);
```